# Is a socket still writable even if your network connection is disconnected?

Tags: c, sockets, select

I have this code which I am using to check if a UDP socket is writeable and then it should send some data if it is writeable. I need to send data  continuously but it should stop sending whenever my internet connection is disconnected. The application is running on a computer which uses a modem but sometimes the modem hangs up but still my application tries to send the data without it knowing that the internet connection is no longer available.

Open the UDP socket

```
int socket_fd;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(999);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ip_of_server; 

socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

Check if socket is writeable then send some data

```
struct timeval tv;
fd_set write_fds;
int ready;

tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
FD_SET(socket_fd, &write_fds);

ready = select(socket_fd + 1, NULL, &write_fds, NULL, &tv);

if ( ready && FD_ISSET(socket_fd, &write_fds) ) 
{

    //Send data here

}
```

My problem is select() still reports that the socket is writeable even if I disconnect my internet connection. Is select() really performs that way? Shouldn't it tell you that the socket is not writable since the network connection is already disconnected?

What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: If you send data, then you get some sort of response, right?

Comment: No error is reported if I send using sendto() it just acts as if it was actually sent.

Comment: You won't get any error report here. The function of `sendto` is just to send the data over the network, it does not check whether or not that data arrived on the other side.

Comment: I was talking about whether or not you get any return data from the receiver. I mean are you using `recvfrom` or some other function like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UDP socket is always writable.

You should only use select() to poll whether a tcp socket is writable.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I have a plan now to just listen for network changes which is said possible on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613521/udp-socket-network-disconnect-behavior-on-windows-linux-mac)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are sending data, I guess you are also receiving some sort of responses from the other side. If that's the case then after sending a request you can wait for reply for a certain period of time, if your data sending mechanism is synchronous (you send a data, receive a response and then again send data). If that interval expires, then you should assume that the network is not working and your connection is broken, so terminate your application.

If your data sending mechanism is not synchronous (you send data continuously regardless of what responses you get) then you should start a thread which will update a timer of some sort. If you don't get any responses before the timer reaches a certain threshold value (which you should decide according to your requirements) then you can assume that the network is broken, and then terminate the app.